# How to join 2 list's together

Tags: haskell

I have a list of tuples `[(a1, b1, c1, d1), (a2, b2, c2 d2), (a3, b3, c3, d3), ..., (a50, b50, c50 ,d50)]` and a second list of Int's, `[2, 1, 4, 3, ..., 50th]`. How do I join these two list's such that the resulting list resembles `[(b1, 2), (b2, 1), (b3, 4), ..., (b50, 50th)]`. Thanks

Comment: Please share your attempt(s) and explain what is going wrong with them.

Comment: First you figure out how to select the second element from a quadruple. Then you use `map` and `zip`.

Answer (score 0):

so you have two lists:

```
tupleList :: [(a, b, c, d)]
tupleList = [(a1, b1, c1, d1), (a2, b2, c2, d2)]

intList :: [Int]
intList = [1, 2]
```

You are going to want map the `tupleList` into a new shape that only holds the values you want:

```
mapTuple :: [(a, b, c, d)] -> [b]
```

Then you are going to want to combine those values with the `intList` to create your final list of tuples:

```
zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b])
```

This second function called `zip` already exists in the prelude.

The first function is going to be something you implement. You can do this with a higher order function called `fmap` which has the signature:

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

This signature means that `fmap` takes a function from `a -> b` and uses it to convert all the `a` values in some `Functor` into `b` values. To make this easier to grok, lets make `fmap` a concrete to `List`, which is a member of the `Functor` typeclass:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

So all we need is to write a function `a -> b`, apply that to `fmap`, and then apply our `[a]` and then we get back a `[b]`!

In this situation our `a` would be `(a, b, c, d)`, our `b` would be `b`, and the function would look like:

```
f :: (a, b, c, d) -> b
```

Applying that function to fmap we would get:

```
fmap f :: [(a, b, c, d)] -> [b]
```

We are almost done. Now we want to use `fmap f` in our main function to to convert the `tupleList` then `zip` the result with our `intList`:

```
mainFunction :: [(a, b, c, d)] -> [Int] -> [(b, Int)]
mainFunction xs ys = zip (mapTuple xs) ys
    where f (a, b, c, d) = b
          mapTuple zs = fmap f zs
```

Tada! Let me know if you have any more questions.